# jQuery to set the height of a div to match the one next to it

Tags: jquery, css

I've got two divs (#mosaicBlog and #mosaicAside). I've got #mosaicAside's CSS set to overflow hidden and want to set #mosaicAside to always be the height of #mosaicBlog (dynamic height page to page).

I thought this would work, but it does not seem to be working. I'm thinking it may just be a syntax problem.

```
$(function(){
    var curHeight = parseInt($("#mosaicBlog").height());
        newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/189) * 189 - 7;
            alert(newHeight );
    $("#blogAside").height(newHeight);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do alert of newHeight are you getting your edefired height

Comment: When I do `alert(newHeight);` It's giving the correct height, but not setting it to the #blogAside

Comment: Can you clarify what it does not seem to be working means? Is it not setting any height, is it not setting the new height, etc?

Comment: @Paul Sham: Sure. Seems to be working in the fact that the jQuery is grabbing the correct computed height of #mosaicBlog. That value is displayed when I do an alert, but it is not being set to the height of blogHeight. If I change the inline css height of #blogAside via firebug to the alerted height of #mosaicBlog, it works. For some reason though, `$("#blogAside").height(newHeight);` is either not being the last jQuery function to set a height on #blogAside (although it is the last function in the js file) or it is not setting at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try after loading document

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var curHeight = parseInt($("#mosaicBlog").height()),
     newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/189) * 189 - 5;
     $("#blogAside").height(newHeight );
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it is wrapped in a document.ready function in my global site.js file.

Comment: `alert(newHeight);` gives the correct height of #mosaicBlog, but not setting it to the #blogAside

Comment: what is the output of `alert(newHeight);`

Comment: On the page I'm looking at, 1317, which is the height of #mosaicBlog. Inspecting it, there's an inline height being set on #blogAside, but my jQuery is the last bit in the file, so it should be the last to run (and set a height)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(function(){` instead of `$({`

http://jsbin.com/uzera7/edit

Comment: @Keefer: no, swap `$({` with `$(function(){` on your first line. p.s. - you mentioned in your post you want it to be the same height as your other DIV.  well your math is wrong. In fact, you shouldn't be doing any math at all, if you want it to be the *same* height.

Comment: @Crayon Violent: Agreed, but it seems to be a few pixels off without some math. I've tried `$(function(){
        var blogCurHeight = parseInt($("#mosaicBlog").height());
        $("#blogAside").height(blogCurHeight);
        alert(blogCurHeight);
    });` but and the value it alerts is within a few pixels, but it's not setting it to the #blogAside div (not overriding the inline height value)

Comment: If you're grabbing the height of `#mosaicBlog`, setting `#blogAside` and it's a few pixels off, did you take into account padding?